# Find all the numbers that can be represented as sum of three distinct elements of an array

Tags: java, c++, dynamic-programming

You have an array A containing N distinct positive integers. You also have an empty set S. Your task to add as many integers as possible to set S. An integer can be added to set S if it can be represented as sum of three distinct elements of array A, and is already not present in the set S.

Example - If N = 5, and array contains 2, 4, 6, 8, 9.
Then the set contains 9 elements --> 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 23

The O(n^3) approach is easy, but will take a lot of time for large arrays. Can someone suggest an efficient way to solve this?

Comment: S can have n^3 elements, e.g. if A elements are 2^i.

Comment: @Ante ``S`` always will have (at most?!) ``comb N M`` elements in the end. Where ``comb N M = N! / M! / (N-M)!``.

Comment: Indeed, the growth is O(f(n)) = n!/(6*(n-3!)) which is O(n^3) so it's perfectly impossible to have a Mir efficient solution than the brute force approach for the worst case

Comment: @BitTickler Yes, comb(n, 3) = n*(n-1)*(n-2)/6, which is ~ (n-1)^3/6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if my solution is actually faster than the brute force approach (expecting giggles and downvotes). But, my solution uses dynamic programming... I think :)

The basic idea is that the solution for the problem (N,1) is trivial. The sum of each 1 tuple of values in the input array is just the input array.

And the solution of the problem (N,M) can use the solution of the problem (N,M-1), by simply mapping over all elements in the (N,M-1) solution, which looks like `Map [Int] Int`. Now, all indices not yet used in a specific element of the (N,M-1) solution need to be combined with each key in the (N,M-1) solution and the sum of the values of the (N,M-1) solution + the value of the unused index creates an element of the (N,M) solution.

And here we have our recursion. And our memoization of the "simpler" results (N,M-1) solution which we use for our solving of the (N,M). And herewith, we did a dynamic programming approach. (recursion + memoization = dynamic programming).

In the language I currently try to learn (Haskell), I came up with this implementation (which is probably considered ugly by many ;)

```hs
import Data.Array
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map


type Lut = Map.Map [Int] Int

foo :: Array Int Int -> Int -> Int -> Lut
-- This is our trivial base case. Create a map for the (N,1) case.
-- "input ! i" means what other languages would write as input[i].
foo input n 1 = Map.fromList [([i],input ! i) | i <- [1..n]]
-- This is the general case, which uses recursion.
foo input n m =
    (Map.fromList . fixKeys . concat . fmap sums) (Map.keys lut)
    where 
        lut :: Lut
        -- Here, the recursion happens. (lut stands for LookUp Table)
        lut = foo input n (m-1)
        all = [1..n]
        sums k =
            -- Here we use our (N,M-1) data to create the output
            -- for this recursion step. 
            -- (forall unused element indices do input[i] + lut[k])
            fmap (\(i,k) -> (i:k,input ! i + query k) ) unused
            where 
                -- The \\ means: difference. 
                -- All indices minus the indices used in a key of a (N,M-1) 
                -- element.
                unused = fmap (\i -> (i,k)) (all \\ k)

        query k =
            case Map.lookup k lut of
                Just v -> v
                Nothing -> error "key cannot not be in the map!"
        -- Remove duplicates (e.g. [1,2,3] and [1,3,2]) by sorting them.
        fixKeys l =
            fmap (\(k,v) -> (sort k,v)) l




to1BasedArray l = listArray (1,length l) l

raw = [2, 4, 6, 8, 9]
input = to1BasedArray raw 

output = foo input (length raw) 3
```

Upon popular demand, here the C++ version of this ... thing :)

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm> // sort()
#include <iostream>

typedef std::vector<int32_t> Data;
typedef std::vector<size_t> Key;
typedef std::map<Key, int32_t> Lut;

auto contains(const Key& indices, size_t index) -> bool
{
    for (auto x : indices)
    {
        if (x == index)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

auto unused(size_t n, const Key& k) -> Key
{
    Key result;
    result.reserve(n);
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (!contains(k, i))
        {
            result.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// 'input' is a vector we use as 1-based (not 0 based) array.
auto foo(const Data& input, size_t n, size_t m) -> Lut
{
    Lut result;
    switch (m)
    {
    case 1:
        for (size_t i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            Key k = { i };
            result[k] = input[i];
        }
        break;
    default:
        {
            Lut lut = foo(input, n, m - 1);
            for (const auto& kv : lut)
            {
                auto uns = unused(n, kv.first);
                for (auto i : uns)
                {
                    auto nk = Key(kv.first.begin(), kv.first.end());
                    nk.push_back(i);
                    std::sort(nk.begin(), nk.end());
                    result[nk] = kv.second + input[i];
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    return result;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Key& values)
{
    bool first = true;
    os << "[";
    for (const auto v : values)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            os << v;
            first = false;
        }
        else
        {
            os << ", " << v;
        }
    }
    os << "]";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    // leading 0 because it is a 1 based array.
    Data data = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9 }; 
    Lut result = foo(data, 5, 3);
    for (auto kv : result)
    {
        std::cout << kv.first << " = " << kv.second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am having problem in understanding your code. Would be good, if you could add some comments, since I don't know Haskell.

Comment: @ArnavKaushik Added a few comments. You should have added your language tags right away and not 14 hours later ;)